# Mouseover function not working for first time

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, mouseover

With this function i want to replace a static image with an animated image (gif) on mouseover. But it's not working only on FIRST mouseover. Is there someone that could help me?
JQuery function:

```
function mouseListener(imageDiv, image, animated, static)
{
  $(function() {
      $(imageDiv).hover(
           function() {
                 $(image).attr("src", animated);
           },
           function() {
                 $(image).attr("src", static);
           }                         
       );                  
   });
            }
```

HTML:

```
 <div onmouseover="mouseListener('#would_youDiv','#would_you','images/would_you.gif','images/would_you.jpg');" id="would_youDiv" class="container">
        <a href="work.html">
            <img id="would_you" class="img-fluid" src="images/would_you.jpg" width="100%" height="100%" />
            <div class="overlay">
                 <div class="text">WOULD YOU</div>
             </div>
         </a>
   </div>
```

Comment: `mouseListener` creates the binding, that will fire the next time the event happens.  Bindings can't fire until they exist.

Comment: And it also will attach one more `.hover` event to `imageDiv` every time you hover on the `div` having the online listener. Get the event attaching out from the event listener.

Comment: @Teemu could you explain me a solution? I'm very new in Javascript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could make this much easier by generalizing the logic with classes and data elements.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.hover-image-container').hover(
    function() {
      //find the image in the container
      var $img = $(this).find('img');
      //set the src to the animaged src on it
      $img.attr('src', $img.data('animated-src'));
    },
    function() {
      //find the image in the container
      var $img = $(this).find('img');
      //set the src to the original src
      $img.attr('src', $img.data('src'));
    }
  );
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container hover-image-container">
  <a href="work.html">
    <img src="images/would_you.jpg" data-src="images/would_you.jpg" data-animated-src="images/would_you.gif" width="100%" height="100%" />
    <div class="overlay">
      <div class="text">WOULD YOU</div>
    </div>
  </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `mouseListener` method is called when the `mouseover` event occurs, which is when it creates the listener to the event, instead of acting on the event. You don't need to add the listener, since you've already registered the function to be called on mouse over, you just need to do the action you want for that event.

You need to either put that binding somewhere else, or create two methods that are bound to `onmouseover` and `onmouseout`.

For example, if you want to go the two methods route (as that's most similar to your current code):

```
<div onmouseover="mouseOverListener('#would_youDiv','#would_you','images/would_you.gif','images/would_you.jpg');" onmouseout="mouseOutListener('#would_youDiv','#would_you','images/would_you.gif','images/would_you.jpg');" id="would_youDiv" class="container">
        <a href="work.html">
            <img id="would_you" class="img-fluid" src="images/would_you.jpg" width="100%" height="100%" />
            <div class="overlay">
                 <div class="text">WOULD YOU</div>
             </div>
         </a>
   </div>
```

And then in your Javascript:

```
function mouseOverListener(imageDiv, image, animated, static) {
    $(image).attr("src", animated);
}

function mouseOutListener(imageDiv, image, animated, static) {
    $(image).attr("src", static);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a js function

HTML

```
<div class="container">
    <a href="work.html">
        <img class="img-fluid" src="images/would_you.jpg" width="100%" height="100%" onmouseover="this.src='images/would_you.gif'" onmouseout="this.src='images/would_you.jpg'"/>
         <div class="overlay">
             <div class="text">WOULD YOU</div>
        </div>
    </a>
</div>
```